# LuaBind get function name

Tags: c++, function, luabind

How to find out which Lua function called my C++ function, if C++ function exported in scripts by luabind, using callstack in MVS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions lua_getstack and lua_getinfo to retrieve various useful debug information including the callstack.